Resizing operating system working area using .NET MAUI
I'm trying to create a .NET MAUI Windows app simmilar to this screenshot I found on an 8 year old post here.
Panel app
The issue is that the app (panel) needs to be separated from the working area (desktop), so no other apps will interfere with it (overlay it, slide behind, ...)
I tried a solution from a 12 year old post here
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                                                int uiAction,
                                                int uiParam,
                                                ref RECT pvParam,
                                                int fWinIni);

private const Int32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;
private const Int32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1;
private const Int32 SPIF_change = SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE;
private const Int32 SPI_SETWORKAREA = 47;
private const Int32 SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public Int32 Left;
    public Int32 Top;   // top is before right in the native struct
    public Int32 Right;
    public Int32 Bottom;
}

private static bool SetWorkspace(RECT rect)
{
   // Since you've declared the P/Invoke function correctly, you don't need to
   // do the marshaling yourself manually. The .NET FW will take care of it.

   bool result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA,
                                      IntPtr.Zero,
                                      ref RECT,
                                      SPIF_change);
   if (!result)
   {
       // Find out the error code
       MessageBox.Show("The last error was: " +
                       Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
   }

   return result;
}

but in .NET MAUI this only resizes the apps for a fraction of a second.

I don't think that the reason it isn't working is that the application is being developed using MAUI. See this more recent question. The accepted answer states that the SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE doesn't work anymore. Instead, use only SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE.
